# Select Inner join and update in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I want to find ranking and then update their rank column according to their id.

My data is as follows (Table **Member**).

```
MEMBER_ID | LOAN_AMOUNT | Rank 
1         | 2,000.00    |  0
2         | 1,000.00    |  0
3         | 4,000.00    |  0
4         | 1,000.00    |  0
```

Now I want to find their ranking and update rank column according to it.
 My general query is something like it:

```
UPDATE
Member AS dest,
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.loan_amount DESC) as [rank],
     t.memeber_id,t.loan_amount
FROM Member
) AS src
SET
dest.rank = src.rank
INNER JOIN dest.memeber_id = src.memeber_id
```

Is there any faster way to update my table?

Comment: Why do you store this information at all, when you can calculate it easily? When you have performance issues, create an index on (loan_amount, member_id).

Comment: For 1000 members I want to show it by pagination. And I dont want calculate it on the fly for each time

Comment: Have you tried it with the index? 1000 members is not really much. Might as well execute in 0.01 seconds, unless you have a potato server.

Comment: no I dont try with index

Comment: Do you mean you won't try, or you haven't tried yet? If the first, what other answer to your question do you expect?

Comment: I haven't tried yet

Answer (score 1):

In mysql the update join sintax should be

```
UPDATE
Member AS dest
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY t.loan_amount DESC) as [rank],
     t.memeber_id,t.loan_amount
FROM Member
) src ON dest.memeber_id = src.memeber_id
SET dest.rank = src.rank
```

anyway you should avoid store data easly calcuated  on fly .. in the same time you perform the select can easly obtain also the rank()